# XML being parsed differently across machines

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Here is my input xml

```
   <app appid="{C38B7539}" lang="en">
      <updatecheck/>
   </app>
```

which gets parsed by following php

```
$xmlObj = simplexml_load_string($xmlStr);
if ($xmlObj === false) {
    // log errors
    return;
}
print_r($xmlObj);
```

Output on Windows (faulty)

```
[app] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [@attributes] => Array
            (
                [appid] => {C38B7539}
                [lang] => en
            )

        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object   <-- Note the 0 instead of updatecheck
            (
            )
    )
```

Output on linux (correct)

```
[app] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [@attributes] => Array
            (
                [appid] => {C38B7539}
                [lang] => en
            )

        [updatecheck] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )
    )
```

As a result `array_key_exists('updatecheck', $xmlObj)` returns `true` under linux and `false` under windows.

How do I fix my parser code to make it work under Windows?

Comment: are they both the same version? if yes, you should have a look to the version number of the underlying libxml2.so (or dll)

Comment: you are using the wrong tool. `array_key_exist` is for arrays. Not SimpleXMLElement objects. Also, you need to understand that the dump of a SimpleXmlElement object is not properly representing the structure. If you want to know whether updatecheck exists, use `isset($app->updatecheck)` where $app is the name of the variable holding your SimpleXmlElement.

Comment: which php versions you are using??

Comment: Voting to reopen after the edit.

Comment: the edit is insubstantial and doesnt reflect that the dump of a SimpleXMLElement cannot be trusted. Also, there is no parser code shown to fix.

Comment: @Gordon the question is clear, at least for me. Could argue that the close is destructive. Note that I am really interested in this post

Comment: @Gordon `isset($app->updatecheck)` solved the problem. Indeed SimpleXMLEObject is not an array and should be treated differently.

Comment: @Gordon Explain why is the question not a real question. I had provided my parser code snippet, the input data, and two outputs - one of them being wrong and the other being expected. What additional info is required to convey the problem?

Comment: @SaptarshiBiswas it's not a question because your base premises are wrong. You assumed a bug when there is no bug. You are simply just not using SimpleXML properly. So the answer is rhetorical. Maybe Too Localized. In any case, there is no problem here.

Comment: @Gordon Question is - how does one know if his premises are wrong unless he posts the questions? Or rather which one of his premises is wrong. Stackoverflow is so valuable because the discussions educate programmers and help remove incorrect assumptions. An aggressive close may erode this value. I'll move on but pl think about it.

Comment: @SaptarshiBiswas while the closing might have been "aggressive", I did also leave you with the correct solution in the comments. So it's not like you were left in the rain. You were educated. You got your solution. There was nothing wrong asking the question. I just think that the question as such doesn't provide any value to future visitors because of the wrong premises. And that's why I closed it.

Comment: @Gordon Clearly, fellow commenters and upvoters disagree with your assessment about the question not providing value to future visitors. Anyhow, I appreciate your time and help. Keep up the good effort of keeping SO clean.